# Doing a STEM Masters after a non-recognized Masters/PhD

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, supervision, industry, africa

I am from a third-world African country. I have a STEM Masters degree from a non-recognized university (ranked 3000 or more worldwide).

I am doing a PhD at the same university where I will be graduating this year (with only 1 publication and some teaching experience). I want to ask if it is possible to pursue another Masters degree in a reputable university (in Canada or Australia) to strengthen my chances of getting an industry job outside Africa.

When I approach supervisors (or the administration) for my application should I:

1. Not disclose my status of being a PhD student (Though I still worry about my gap in my CV)? or
2. Tell them the truth of having a PhD (which I think will ruin my chances of being accepted)? or
3. Tell them I have a Masters,  but I was doing some teaching and research assistant activities after my Masters (trying to not disclose my status)?

Comment: Ignore the ranking of the university. Did you do good work there? Is your advisor supportive? Are you changing fields?

Comment: @Buffy Not really a good work. But the article is published in 5+ impact factor journal. My supervisors are not supportive (I sometimes have problems with them)

Comment: Do you still need an answer?